# how to save the content of the rich text editor created by react-draft-wysiwyg library to MongoDB database using Prisma?

Tags: mongodb, next.js, prisma

```
const DocumentEditor = () => {
  const [editorState, setEditorState] = useState(EditorState.createEmpty());
  const onEditorStateChange = (newEditorState) => {
    setEditorState(newEditorState);
   try {
     //??????????????

      console.log("Document created:", createdDocument);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error creating document:", error);
    }
  };
  return (
      <Editor
        editorState={editorState}
        onEditorStateChange={onEditorStateChange}
      />
    
  );
};
export default DocumentEditor;
```

How to save the content of the rich text editor created by the react-draft-wysiwyg library to the MongoDB database using Prisma?
A document's contents are saved on the database. I need help, please

Answer (score 1):

First install draftjs-to-html library and do necessary imports

```js
import draftToHtml from 'draftjs-to-html' 
import { convertToRaw} from 'draft-js'
```

Then convert EditorState content to HTML before saving it to the database. Not sure how you are planning to handle the database update, but this should give you a clear idea,

```js
 const submit = async (EditorState) => {
    try {
      const contentState = EditorState.getCurrentContent()
      const contentRaw = convertToRaw(contentState)
      const contentHtml = draftToHtml(contentRaw)

      const createdDocument = await prisma.document.create({
        data: {
          content: contentHtml,
        },
      });

      console.log("Document created:", createdDocument);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error creating document:", error);
    }
  }
```